# c++ pass by reference issue

Tags: c++, pass-by-reference

How can I pass a reference to a collection to another class in order to have that class modify it? Trying it the intuitive way (i.e. passing and storing a reference `collection& c` and then using that reference for updates) doesn't seem to work:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test{
private:
    std::vector<int> testvec;

public:
    Test(std::vector<int>& vec){
        testvec = vec;
    }

    void add(int i){
        testvec.push_back(i);
    }

    void report(){
        std::cout << "testvec has " << testvec.size() << " items" << "\n";
        for(int i : testvec)
            std::cout << i << " ";
        if(!testvec.empty())
            std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> myVec;

    Test test(myVec);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        test.add(i);
    }

    test.report();
    std::cout << "\n";
    std::cout << "myVec has " << myVec.size() << " items" << "\n";
    for(int i : myVec)
        std::cout << i << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

will give me

> testvec has 10 items
>
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> myVec has 0 items

Comment: `testvec = vec;` makes a copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are creating `Test` object you are passing `myVec` by reference, but `testvec` is in fact a value. So it will copy the value of `myVec` at that time, which is a empty vector.
Change

```
std::vector<int> testvec;
```

to

```
std::vector<int>& testvec;
```

and it will work. But you also need to adjust constructor:

```
Test(std::vector<int>& myVec) : testvec(myVec) {}
```

**Explenation to comment:**

Since member `testvec` is now a [reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)) then it must point to some existing object in the memory.

It must be initialized while construction of instance of `Test` class, otherwise `testvec` would not be valid reference type, so program would be ill-formed.

[Initialization list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) is triggered before constructor body. It is also the place where all members are assigned with default value, or with specified one. For reference the only valid value is existing object in memory (or reference) so you must explicitly tell the reference members the value with which they have to me initialized with.

Eg.

```
class A {
    int& t;
    A(int& T) : t(T) {} // * OK
    A(int& T) { t = T; } // ** ill-formed
}
```

(*) would be ok because `t` is set with `T` before calling constructor body

(**) would not be ok because `t` is set AFTER initialization list, so after the step where default values are set.

Comment: Thank you. I can't really see what's going on, though. Could you elaborate on why the constructor must be adjusted or what this adjustment does, exactly?

Answer (score -1):

It's not working because you are using pass by value instead of pass by reference. To use pass by reference in C++, your actual argument should be like `Test test(& myVec);` and while at the receiving end of the function it the argument should be like `Test(std::vector<int>* vec)` (in your case it is constructor). Always in pass by reference one has to send the address of the variable and in pass by value one has to send the actual value of the variable.

you should simply use the

```
std::vector<int> *testvec;
```

for which you will be sending address of "myVec"

```
Test test(& myVec);
```

and constructor should be like:

```
Test(std::vector<int>* vec) {
    testvec = vec;  
}
```

and rest everywhere for

```
testvec.properties();
```

you have to use

```
testvec->properties();
```

then it will work for sure.

Here is the link to the solution: http://ideone.com/7DWJ9O

Comment: This could be a good answer if there were an explanation of the "why". Without that, it comes across like a magic formula, which does not help understanding... (I'm not the downvoter, I'm just explaining why I didn't *up*vote.)